# PHP popen does not execute with "start /B" in Main Server

Tags: php, iis, popen

I am working in a IIS server with php7.3 and My code segment looks like this

`<?php 
   fclose(popen("start /B php C:\\mydir\\exec.php", "r"));
?>`

Code segment of "exec.php"  is given below (actual code executes a long process of joining tables and exporting as a csv file). I need "exec.php" to be run in background without being waiting for its completion.

```
<?php
   $f = fopen("text" . date("H_i_s") .".txt","w");
   fwrite($f,"test");
   fclose($f);
?>
```

These segments runs just fine when I remove "start /B", but not with it.